# SQL version of Wordnet

Tags: wordnet

The original Wordnet is not in SQL format. I found these two as SQL converters

http://www.semantilog.org/wn2sql.html#word
https://wnsql.sourceforge.net/

There may be others.
Could you help me in choosing between them or suggesting any others?

Comment: Dear Handsome, could you please detail, what exactly you‘re looking for in these converters? Depending on what you want to achieve, recommendations might be very different. Please edit that into your question, as that will increase probability of receiving a meaningful answer. Ty

Comment: The Wordnet site  includes [links](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/related-projects) to some of the widely used application programming interfaces available for accessing WordNet using various programming languages and environments.

Comment: @Grimaldi could you advise what is better for each application? I need SQL version of Wordnet

Comment: If you're looking for lookup of synonyms and iterating the connections between synsets and such, then I'd recommend the RDF version of wordnet. If you're intending to calculate counts, sums and/or create tables from wordnet, then use one of the SQL converterts. Looking at the schemas, there's little difference between those two. Both  more or less follow the wordnet structure and do not add any denormalization to speed up queries, AFAICT. If you'd provide some hints of what exactly you're planning to use wordnet wfor, other's may be able to help. I am not.